# Use a complex whereIn with Laravel's query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

We have an SQL query that works fine on its own.

```
SELECT id FROM `tblinvoices` WHERE `id` IN ( 
    SELECT invoiceid FROM `tblinvoiceitems` WHERE `type` = 'Addon' AND `relid` = 1479 AND `userid` = 9554
) AND `userid` = 9554 AND `status` = 'Unpaid'
```

I have tried to dig through and find a good query builder format that would work with these sub selects but keep getting unexpected results. This is what I have built:

```
$db = Capsule::table('tblinvoices')->select('id')->where('userid', 9554)->where('status', 'Unpaid')->whereIn('id', function($query)
{
    $query->select('invoiceid')->from('tblinvoiceitems')->where('type', 'Addon')->where('relid', 1479)->where('userid', 9554);
});
```

I seem to be misunderstanding how laravel's query works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm stupid I forgot the `get();` at the end of my query:

```
$db = Capsule::table('tblinvoices')->select('id')->where('userid', 9554)->where('status', 'Unpaid')->whereIn('id', function($query)
    {
        $query->select('invoiceid')->from('tblinvoiceitems')->where('type', 'Addon')->where('relid', 1479)->where('userid', 9554);
    })->get();
```

Comment: haha, yeah I was an idiot. In the moment it didn't let me mark the answer as solved but for those that stumble here from google the query in the answer above works.